# Tornado behind Nginx, should I use TCP nodelay config in python or nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, tcp, websocket, tornado

I have a Tornado server running behind Nginx reverse proxy. The proxy is configured with `tcp_nodelay: on`. I see there's also an option to call `WebSocketHandler.set_nodelay(True)` on a WebSocket instance once it's connected.

Do these two create the same effect? Are there pro's con's for using one over the other? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you are using `nodelay` and proxies, you should turn it on at all levels to see any benefit. Otherwise any piece of the system that doesn't have `nodelay` will insert the delays you're trying to avoid.

According to the nginx [docs for `tcp_nodelay`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#tcp_nodelay), it applies only when a connection is in the keep-alive state, so it will have no effect on proxied websockets.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @ben-darnell! Regarding the second part, you're saying that any proxied ws over nginx won't transition into keep-alive state? So doesn't that mean only the Tornado ws handler's method will have any effect in that stack?

Comment: Websocket connections are never in the keep-alive state, so this setting would not apply to them. There may be other settings that do apply, or it may be on by default in this case. Unless nginx turns on `TCP_NODELAY`, turning it on at the Tornado level is unlikely to have much effect, since your packets will be sent to nginx immediately but when nagle's algorithm applies they'll be held up at nginx.

Comment: OK, so at least I'm assuring messages on that path are sent immediately. Now need to get that other piggy to wiggle (: